# How to unit test struct constructor

Tags: unit-testing, struct, rust

If I have a struct like:

```
struct Foo {
  bar: int,
  baz: bool
}
```

and a default constructor like:

```
impl Foo {
  fn default() -> ~Foo {
    Foo{bar: 0, baz: false}
  }
}
```

I'd want a unit test for my constructor:

```
#[test]
fn test_foo_default() {
  let foo1 = Foo::default();
  let foo2 = ~Foo{bar: 0, baz: false};
  // What to put here to compare them?
}
```

How do I easiest compare the two structs to make sure they are the same with regards to content, type and ownership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the compiler derive the Eq trait for Foo (if possible), and then check for equality with the `assert_eq!` macro. The macro also requires Show to be implemented for some reason, so let's derive it as well. Your original default() function doesn't actually compile because it attempts to return a `Foo` where a `~Foo` was promised. `Foo` and `~Foo` are actually different types, but you can dereference a `~Foo` and compare that.

You may also be interested in the Default trait.

```
#[deriving(Eq,Show)]
struct Foo {
    bar: int,
    baz: bool
}

impl Foo {
    fn default() -> ~Foo {
        ~Foo{bar: 0, baz: false}
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_foo_default() {
    let foo1 = Foo::default();
    let foo2 = ~Foo{bar: 0, baz: false};
    assert_eq!(foo1,foo2);
}

#[test]
fn test_foo_deref() {
    let foo1 = Foo::default();
    let foo2 = Foo{bar: 0, baz: false};
    assert_eq!(*foo1,foo2);
}
```

Comment: This works great up 'til the point where I have a struct with a pointer to a trait, and then it no longer can derive Eq or Show.